# Zeros of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $D$ be a connected open $\mathbb{C}$ and denote by $\overline{D}$ its closure. If a function $f$ is continuous in $\overline{D}$, is analytic in D and $$|f(z)-1|<1 \forall z\in \overline{D}\setminus D$$ show that $f$ has no zeros in $D$.

Adding the hypothesis that $D$ is limited, the solution is simple using the Maximo Module Principle. But without this I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Well, without the boundedness assumption it need not be true. Try to construct a counterexample.

Comment: If $f(z_0)=0$ then $1=|-1|=|f(z_0)-1|<1$, which is impossible. No boundedness needed. what needs to be precised is where is the inequality true?

Comment: Ah, right, the "on $\partial D$" is missing.

Comment: Excuse me. Just now I saw that the question was incomplete. @Pp.. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:\{z:\ |z-1|\geq1\}\to\mathbb{C}$ by $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{2}+1$. For $|z-1|=1$ we have $$|f(z)-1|=\frac{|z-1|}{2}=\frac{1}{2}<1.$$